# Accessing a NSManagedObject causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, memory-management, nsmanagedobject

**Update: Tidied up question and made it a bit clearer**

I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes on a `NSManagedObject`.

I have a `Sentence` managed object that I pass to a modal view (`addStoryItem`) like so:

```
addStoryItem.sentence = (Sentence*)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

`AddStoryItem` is set to retain `Sentence`:

```
@property (retain) Sentence *sentence;
```

Sometimes the user needs to do something that shows another modal (on top of `addStoryItem`) - which doesn't affect this object, but it does take a copy of a NSMutableSet - `sentence.audiosets`

If I they do view this modal I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` whenever I try to access or set the sentence object or its properties, once the user is returned to addStoryItem

- There is a current managed object context & fetched results controller
- everything works fine unless I show that modal view controller (which, afaik, doesn't have anything to do with the sentence object)
- Zombies is on, but it doesn't tell me anything (BRAINS?)

Here's a simple summary of what goes on:

- user selects row in tableview
- I get object from table and set the modal's sentence property then display the modal with the fetchedResultsController
- I display a string, image and set a nsset from the sentence to ui aspects of the modal
- if the user needs to modify the nsset they display another modal, with a copy of the first nsset (which doesn't change or access the sentence object)
- if I try to set a property in the sentence after closing the 2nd modal (or NSLOG sentence) - `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**As far as I'm concerned I own sentence**. Other properties of addStoryItem are still hanging around in memory - but sentence isn't there when I try to get to it. Yes, I release sentence in addStoryItem's dealloc - but that's not being called (I have a log statement in there).

Can you help? Happy to provide more code or info. Pretty frustrated!

Comment: Your first modal may be getting released while you have the 2nd modal open.

Comment: @mark I thought so too - and that may be part of the problem. But I can replicate the error just in the tableview so I think I must be doing something wrong selecting the object to pass in the first place. Updated question.

Comment: Which line of code is the one that causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Any line accessing (NSLog) or setting [sentence setText:@"foo"] the sentence object. In the tableView example the NSLog@"sentenceToUpdate: %@" line.

Comment: Check to see if fetchedResultsController is nil before you try and use it.

Comment: Tried that - I always NSLog fRC and it isn't nil in these cases. Also added an explicit check if(fRC == nil) but it's not.

Comment: Did you retain or copy the sentence property on your AddStoryItem class? copy won't work!

Comment: Retain. I copy a NSSet property inside the sentence object though.

Comment: If you run with zombies, what's the first deallocated object it warns about an access to?

Comment: I'm running with zombies but it doesn't give me any warning - it just crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `sentenceToUpDate` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Surely, this reference will be forgotten as soon as you are out of that method.

Rather, you should assign the retrieved object to your retained property, like this:

```
self.sentence = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now the instance should be retained as expected.

Another possible culprit is your copy of the `NSSet`. Try creating a new `NSSet` to make sure you are not effecting the entity:

```
NSSet *setToBePassedToModal = [[NSSet alloc] 
                                initWithSet:entity.toManyRelationship];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no luck - I changed the assignment as you suggested to addStoryItem.sentence = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; but I still have the same problem.